# Mongo 3.6 - Resolve referenced object in nested list of objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, lookup

I have a collection containing documents on the following format:

**db.companies.find({})**

```
{
    'name': 'ABC Trading Ltd',
    'telephone': '01292 480 485',
    'comments': [{
        'user': 'joe.bloggs@example.com',
        'date': 'example',
        'text': 'This is an example comment.'
     },
     {
        'user': 'jane.bloggs@example.com',
        'date': 'example',
        'text': 'This is an example comment.'
     }] 
}
```

I also have a users collection that looks like the following:

**db.users.find({})**

```
{
    'email': 'joe.bloggs@example.com',
    'firstname': 'Joe',
    'lastname': 'Bloggs'
},
{
    'email': 'jane.bloggs@example.com',
    'firstname': 'Jane',
    'lastname': 'Bloggs'
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is use *$lookup* so that the results of the final query look like so:

```
{
    'name': 'ABC Trading Ltd',
    'telephone': '01292 480 485',
    'comments': [{
        'user': {
              'email': 'joe.bloggs@example.com',
              'firstname': 'Joe',
              'lastname': 'Bloggs'
        },
        'date': 'example',
        'text': 'This is an example comment.'
     },
     {
        'user': {
              'email': 'jane.bloggs@example.com',
              'firstname': 'Jane',
              'lastname': 'Bloggs'
        },
        'date': 'example',
        'text': 'This is an example comment.'
     }] 
}
```

Now I know that I can lookup values using something like this:

```
db.companies.aggregate[{"$lookup": {
           "from": "users",
           "localField": "user",
           "foreignField": "email",
           "as": "user"
        }}, {"$addFields": {
            "user": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$user", 0]}
        }}]
```

However, this would only work if the user was top level in the document, and there was only one field that needed replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.companies.aggregate([{$unwind : '$comments'},{"$lookup": {
           "from": "users",
           "localField": "comments.user",
           "foreignField": "email",
           "as": "user"
        }}, {$addFields : {'comments.user': {"$arrayElemAt": ["$user", 0]}}},{$project : {user :0}}, 
        {$group:{_id:'$_id', comments:{$push : '$comments'}, data: {$first :'$$ROOT'}}}, {$addFields :{'data.comments':'$comments'}}, {$replaceRoot:{'newRoot': '$data'}}])
```

**Note :** Usually we don't have to `$unwind` **comments** for `$lookup` unless needed as different valued objects needs mapping, Plus if possible try to use `$match` as first stage & proper indexes for better performance on `$lookup`'s.

Comment: So how would I go about this without using $unwind?

Match is already being used, i just removed it to simplify my question.

Comment: @Slepton : Ok using $match as first stage & if your dataset is not too large(millions of documents) after that then you're good to go, it's not like we should not use $unwind - we've to use it for certain cases -it's quiet normal, but my suggestion is use it properly, like not on entire documents using it after filters($match) should be good enough, as long as your queries performance is good then things are ok :-) !!

Comment: perfect. Yes, I'm actually only retrieving a single document, but need to use aggregation-framework to do lookup.